# NSXMLParser error, how to get rid of invalid chars inside XML tags?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding, nsxmlparser

Hi everyone and thanks in advance for your help.

This is the situation:
I'm consuming a webservice that returns me a soap message in the following way:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <getMessagesResponse xmlns="urn:DefaultNamespace">
   <getMessagesReturn xmlns="">
    &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;ISO-8859-1&quot; ?&gt;
&lt;contact&gt;
A message with escaped values like &amp; &lt; &gt;
&lt;/contact&gt;
</getMessagesReturn>
  </getMessagesResponse>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I use NSUTF8StringEncoding to read the getMessagesReturn child and it generates me the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1">
        <contact>
        A message with escaped values like & < >
        </contact>;
```

My problem is that it also unescape the & < > inside the contact tag, and of course the NSXMLParser throws an error because these are invalid characters inside a XML tag.

My Question is, How can I avoid this? Is there a way to escape back only the tags message contents before passing the info to the Parser?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit I use:

```
[NSString stringWithCString:(char*)elementText encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I don't know what you are using to convert your data to UTF8, but NS-apis does not escape entities if I remember well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you control the web service? The correct way to pass getMessageReturn is with a CDATA. Otherwise, the correct encoding would be like this (note the message itself and the extra &amp's)

```
<getMessagesReturn xmlns="">
    &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;ISO-8859-1&quot; ?&gt;
&lt;contact&gt;
A message with escaped values like &amp;amp; &amp;lt; &amp;gt;
&lt;/contact&gt;
</getMessagesReturn>
```

But CDATA is much easier, and this is what it's for. If nothing else, you can use string substitution to insert the CDATA before parsing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rob, but if the content of the getMessageReturn is an entire XML, I need to parse it anyway or write some code to find the info inside the CDATA string. I guess that maybe I can talk with the webservice provider and see if they can encapsulate every tag contents inside a CDATA block, in that way I would be able to read the XML properly and capture the data inside every tag with the foundCData method of the NSXMLParser right?

Comment: If you're embedding XML inside of XML, then you should use CDATA. You don't have to make every tag contents CDATA. You would use foundCData for this particular tag. The result would be a string that you would then need to start over with (since it's a completely different document). BTW, to inject the CDATA by hand, you can use an NSScanner to find the right places in the string, and then insert it. It's better to fix the original XML, though; it's invalid.

Comment: Thanks Rob, your answer leads me to found the solution that was asking the WS provider to encapsulate every tag contents inside a CDATA block and use the foundCDATA from the NSXMLParserDelegate to get the info.